# Uploading images into cloudinary in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a question,

How do I upload images into cloudinary in bootstrap and get a public ID instead of a auto-generated ID?

Need advice for this thanks!

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#expirydate").val(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    $("#upload_widget_opener").click(function() {
      cloudinary.openUploadWidget({
        cloud_name: 'cloud name',
        upload_preset: '',
        public_id: ""
      }, function(error, result) {
        console.log(error, result)
      });
    });
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      funct1(e);
      window.alert("Your advertisement is created.");
      location.reload();
    });
  });
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context before anyone on here will be able to help you. Please provide your goals, what you've tried, and any relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: Currently my codes are:

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#expirydate").val( moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') );
 $("#upload_widget_opener").click(function() {

   cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'cloud name', upload_preset: '', public_id:""},   
      function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
                
     });
 
 $("form").submit(function(e){
 
 
  e.preventDefault();
   funct1(e);
   window.alert("Your advertisement is created.");
   location.reload();
   
   
  });
});

Comment: You'll have to put them in the actual question

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to set the uploaded file's public ID, instead of letting Cloudinary to randomly generate it for you, you can indeed pass the `public_id` parameter as you did. However, you should also make sure that '**Disallow public ID**' is disabled (set to '**No**') in the relevant upload preset's settings. Note that to ensure secure usage, overwriting previously uploaded images sharing the same public ID is prevented.